# Increase width of svg rectangle bar in google chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I am working on Google Timeline chart and the bar width in each row is very smaller in size.

I want to increase the size of that bar but it was tough luck. Using the inspect element of browser, I could able to increase the size but when I tried to apply the same in my code, it isnt working.

Here is what I got from Inspect element section related to SVG

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="6000" height="40.992" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#ffffff"></rect>
```

Below is my google timeline chart code:

```
<html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
        var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'President' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
        dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
        dataTable.addRows([
          [ 'Test1', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1789, 4, 01) ],
          [ 'Test2',      new Date(1789, 4, 02),  new Date(1789, 4, 03) ],
          [ 'Test3',  new Date(1789, 4, 04),  new Date(1789, 4, 06) ]]);

        chart.draw(dataTable);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
            </head>
            <body>
                
                <div id="chart_div">
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Can anyone please let me know how to increase the width of bars or svg rectangle in this google chart.

Thanks!

Comment: the width of the bars represented by the the rows in the data table is driven by the start and end dates. and will be scaled based on the width of the overall chart. the only way to increase the width, is to make the overall chart wider, and / or increase the time span between the start and end dates.

Comment: @whitehat, when i increase the width of chart like around 6000, the timeline is showing each day which is helpful. The issue here is that, the bar is not occupying complete cell and is displaying as a small dash. In a nutshell, increasing the width of the chart didn’t work

Answer (score 0):

you can increase the width with the help of options in google charts,

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

```
var options = {
        title: "Timeline chart",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
      };
        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Comment: @kbhitest, using this solution, i could able to increase the width of chart but not the bars. groupwidth is not increasing the width even i increase it more

Comment: note: `groupWidth` is not a valid option for Timeline, it is used for Column / Bar charts.

Comment: Does increasing the label font size help? @WhiteHat